# return promise if download to the db is finished

Tags: javascript

hi I have such a code:

```
export const apiAddTodo = async (todoName, todoDesription, picture) => {
    const todo = {
      name: todoName,
      body: todoDesription,
      status: false
    };

    if (picture) {
      const snapshot = await images(new Date().getTime()).put(picture);
      todo.image = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs;
    }

    return db.push(todo);
};
```

this code work with async/await but I want to rewrite it to the promise based just for the leaning purposes. In the if statemnt I need to wait for the image loading and after that proceed to the db.push method. Can somebody help me with that?
I tried such a code but it won't help me:

```
if (picture) {
    return new Promise( res => {
        images(new Date().getTime()).put(picture).then( snapshot => {
        todo.image = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs;
        res(todo);
      });
   )}         
  }
```

Comment: then is used after resolution of promise

Answer (score 0):

> The only difference is that, you are not pushing `todo` to `db`. The rest
>   looks good.

```
if (picture) {
    return new Promise( res => {
        images(new Date().getTime()).put(picture).then( snapshot => {
        todo.image = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs;
        db.push(todo)
        res(todo);
      });
   )}  
}
```

Comment: I need to push it only if there is one so I just create image in todo, if picture is empty I just write itt as it is

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: todo are written without image, the code doesn't wait for the image to be loaded

Comment: it is here already, this is all the function that responsible for that

Comment: I just need instead of async/await use promise here

Comment: yeah the promise code you have written is correct, except that you have missed `db.push(todo)`

Comment: is `db.push(todo)` an async function?

Comment: it is not behavior that I need, I do not need to write image in the sam promise with other todo. Todo only should be pushed to db if image was pushed correcеtly. If there in no image, todo pushed without it, if there is image image should be pushed, all code wait for this and after that in the bottom todo is pushed witg the image property inside